# Laravel HasMany relationships count

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, has-many

I have a user model with hasMany relationship.

User has many unreviewed files and im trying to get the total number of unreviewed files.
this is how i did it. i just wonder if there is a better way.

```
    $users = User::families()->whereHas('unreviewedcovidfiles')->withCount('unreviewedcovidfiles')->get();
    $totalfiles = 0;
    foreach($users as $user){
        $totalfiles += $user->unreviewedcovidfiles_count;
    }
    return $totalfiles;
```

Comment: Why don't just get the count from the model of `unreviewedcovidfiles` directly?

Comment: This is a multitenant app. i didnt wanna add tenant_id column. then would have been much easier i know. i filter the files through users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you have a `user` relationship on `unreviewedcovidfiles` model.

You can get the count from the model of `unreviewedcovidfiles` directly and filter the users by tenant via `whereHas` method:

```
$totalfiles  = Unreviewedcovidfile::whereHas('user', function($query){
    $query->families();
})->count();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Alternatively, use the `sum` method for the collection:

```
$users = User::families()->whereHas('unreviewedcovidfiles')->withCount('unreviewedcovidfiles')->get();
$totalfiles = $users->sum('unreviewedcovidfiles_count');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sum

Comment: I go with the second suggestion. Thanks. Sometimes the solution is right there but you cant see it :) Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [`hasManyThrough` relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through). After defining relationship you can count simply using `count()` on relationship.